# Live Streaming CNN

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming

Does anybody have a solution to live streaming TV for example CNN Go?
I've installed hal-flash, Adobe flash and installed media codecs. I'm trying to live stream CCN with Chrome browser and Firefox with no luck.
I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 on an HP laptop. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cnn.com/help/cnngo-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

CNN Go has an extensive list of browser requirements that demand, for example, that you allow all cookies and remove any blocks that might prevent CNN from scraping data from your browser.  It also only mentions support for ff and chrome in a windows or mac environment.  I posted a link to their troubleshooting list in the comments section.

Comment: Did it answer your question or at least help I hope?

Comment: Yeah it helped, but still no resolution. I think it may have something to do with protected content and open source not jiving. Thanks Jones!